# Switch profile of current Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to switch the profile of an already-opened Terminal window? Let's say I already have a Terminal window opened with Basic profile. Can I switch it to Grass profile?

I seem to only be able to change profiles if I open a new Terminal window.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can change the profile of an active window by doing the following:

- Right click in the open space of the Terminal window (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Choose "Show Inspector"
- Click on the "Settings" header in the Inspector window
- Choose a new profile for the current window

EDIT:

In macOS 10.14.6 the Terminal.app Inspector profile-selection list looks like this:

[image: macOS 10.14.6 Terminal.app Inspector profile-selection list]

Comment: A real life saver!

Comment: AND PRESS THE TINY ``Default`` to apply the profile, otherwise it doesn't stick. +1 for this answer.

Comment: Excellent!  I must have ignored the `Inspector` option a hundred times!! Wonder who picked that name - `Inspector`?... as in "Inspector Clouseau"?